# Open GPKG, query layers and save to new GPKG

Tags: r, sql

I have recently started to use SQL and geopackages queries in R. I know how to open it, access the individual layers (geometry and tables), and select and process individual layers. But, I don't know how to finally store the all the data data again within the new geopackage?

This is the **simple workflow**:

[image]

I'm very new in SQL, so I control my data storage via ArcGIS catalog. And I see, that I can succesfully attach a geometry file, but not the associated table.

[image]

Please, **what is a correct way to save my geometry, as well as selected table to a new geopackage**?

Dummy data are available here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zl85ym8wzvzwskd/AAAhODNM5O1lRLb7hOsYCg6za?dl=0

My code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/.../Dropbox/data")

library(rgdal) 
library(dplyr)  # for SQL: http://jsta.github.io/2016/07/14/geopackage-r.html
library(RSQLite)

# Define inputs
gpkgName = "MV_K3243G.gpkg"

# SElect tables to store in new .gpkg 
stratumName = "treestratum"
standName = "stand"

# Define new .gpkg
outGpkgName = "out_MV_K3243G.gpkg" 

# Read feature geometry and attribute table 
fc.shape = readOGR(gpkgName, layer = standName)

# Create connection to SQL database to read table I want to copy
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), 
                      dbname = gpkgName)

dbListTables(con)  # List and plot all tables in SQL database

# Perform some data.frame operation on the table
stratum_df<-as.data.frame(tbl(con, stratumName))  

# save geometry into new .gpkg DOES NOT WORK!!!
writeOGR(fc.shape, 
         dsn = outGpkgName, 
         layer = "stand", 
         driver = "GPKG",
         overwrite_layer=TRUE)


# Write the table to .gpkg
outCon = dbConnect(SQLite(),
                   dbname=paste0(".", "/", outGpkgName))


dbWriteTable(conn = outCon,       # This one does not "stratum_df" table to my .gpkg, only keep the feature geometry "stand"
             name = stratumName,  # How to rewrite it? 
             value = stratum_df)
```

Between data input and data output I would like clip some features and query my data frames, so I don't just simply wont to create a copy of my input geopackage.

Comment: This code works fine for me (OSX 10.14.5, rgdal 1.4-3, R 3.5.1). What versions are you running?

Comment: Hi @Simbamangu, does the script add a second table to the output .gpkg? For me, it only keeps one output table `stand`. I am on Windows 10, 64 , rgdal 1.4-4, R 3.5.1

Comment: You're using GDAL? to create the GPKG and ArcGIS to read it? I'd try another client that reads GPKG to ensure that ArcGIS isn't "wrong". The package could be correct as @Simbamangu infers. IE. You might be doing everything right, it's ArcGIS that could be wrong. (Which version of ArcCatalog are you using?)

Comment: @maycca yes, it outputs a second non-geometry table to the GPKG.

Comment: Thank you @Simbamangu. Now it works. For some reason, it worked after I restarted my computer. I will close the question